# anzo query console results URI compression

Tags: sparql, anzograph

Suppose i have data inserted into ANZO:

```
insert data {<a> rdf:type <c1>}
```

When I issue query:

```
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
select ?s ?p ?o where {bind(rdf:type as ?p). ?s ?p ?o}
```

I've got the answer from console:

```
 s | p                                               | o  
---+-------------------------------------------------+----
 a | http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type | c1
```

Now my question: is any way in ANZO I can get answer to console where rdf:type is shown as compressed URI:

```
 s | p        | o  
---+----------+----
 a | rdf:type | c1
```